# Concentric ring of ellipses

Tags: processing

I'm trying to recreate an array of increasing sized circles that each are being divided to create points to create ellipses that pulsate. I know how to divide each circle by a num of points and draw ellipses. And I know how to create a series of concentric circles, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around putting them together. When I do, I receive a result that looks like this..

[image: Circle Overlap]

This result is happening because each individual ellipse is adding a number of ellipses in increasing distances from the original ellipse. Nevertheless, I'm not sure how to fix the original issue of having a series of circles divided by a number of points to create ellipses.

Thanks.

```java
Blackhole b;

void setup() {
  size(750, 500);
  smooth();
  b = new Blackhole();
}

void draw() {
  b.divide();
  b.display();

}

class Blackhole {
  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  PVector center;
  float speed = 0;

  int [] eSize = {0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175};
  float radius = 100;
  int numPoints = 16;
  float angle = TWO_PI/(float)numPoints;
  float [] [] xyArray;

  Blackhole() {
    location = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
    velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
    acceleration = new PVector(.0, 0);
  }

  void divide() {
    xyArray = new float [numPoints][3]; 
    for (int i=0; i<numPoints; i++) { 
      float x = radius*sin(angle*i)+width/2;
      float y = radius*cos(angle*i)+height/2;
      xyArray[i][0] = x; 
      xyArray[i][1] = y;
    }
   }



  void display() {
    background(#202020);


    speed = speed + 0.05;
    float pulse = noise(speed);
    pulse = map(pulse, 0, 1, 150, 175);

    noFill();
    stroke(255, 100);
     for ( int j = 0; j < eSize.length; j++) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
        float x = xyArray[i][0];
         float y = xyArray[i][1];
         ellipse(width/2, height/2, pulse + eSize[j], pulse + eSize[j]);
         ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a circle of circles shouldn't be complicated and you already understand how to the polar to cartesian coordinate system conversion.
Something as simple as this would work:

```java
/*
    draws a large circle with each vertex drawn as a smaller circle
    sides = circle detail, the more sides, the more detaild the circle will be
    largeRadius = large circle radius
    smallRadius = radius of each small circle
*/
void circleOfCircles(int sides,float largeRadius, float smallRadius){
  float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < sides; i++){
    float x = cos(angleIncrement * i) * largeRadius;
    float y = sin(angleIncrement * i) * largeRadius;
    ellipse(x,y,smallRadius,smallRadius);
  }
}
```

Which using your values would look like this:

```java
float speed = 0;
int [] eSize = {0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175};
float radius = 100;
int numPoints = 16;


void setup(){
  size(750,500);
  smooth();
}
void draw(){
  background(#202020);
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5);

  speed = speed + 0.05;
  float pulse = noise(speed);
  pulse = map(pulse, 0.0, 1.0, 150, 175);

  noFill();
  stroke(255, 100);
   for ( int j = 0; j < eSize.length; j++) {
     circleOfCircles(numPoints,pulse + eSize[j], 5);
   }
}
/*
    draws a large circle with each vertex drawn as a smaller circle
    sides = circle detail, the more sides, the more detaild the circle will be
    largeRadius = large circle radius
    smallRadius = radius of each small circle
*/
void circleOfCircles(int sides,float largeRadius, float smallRadius){
  float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < sides; i++){
    float x = cos(angleIncrement * i) * largeRadius;
    float y = sin(angleIncrement * i) * largeRadius;
    ellipse(x,y,smallRadius,smallRadius);
  }
}
```

If the polar to cartesian conversion is confusing, you can simply [isolate transformations using pushMatrix() and popMatrix()](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/):

```java
void circleOfCircles(int sides,float largeRadius, float smallRadius){
  float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < sides; i++){
    pushMatrix();
      rotate(angleIncrement * i);
      translate(largeRadius,0);
      ellipse(0,0,smallRadius,smallRadius);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Generally it's best to keep things are simple as possible.
You are using a class and that's great! It's good to encapsulate functionality.
It will make it easier to plug into other sketches in the future.

However, I there are some unused variables in your class:

```java
PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  PVector center;
```

Some of these are initialised in the constructor, but never used again.

The main issue in terms of drawing circles of circles is around the `divide()` and `xyArray`. In `divide()` you are computing points around a circle with a single radius, although in `display()` it looks like you want to use varying radii.
I've removed the `divide()` function which removed the need to use the `xyArray` and loop over it twice (once to set positions, then to read it). Notice instead of `radius`, `pulseRadius` is used now which takes `pulse` and `eSize` into account.

Here is a simplified version of your code using `radius`, but also `pulse` and `eSize` which is probably what you were trying to do:

```java
Blackhole b;

void setup() {
  size(750, 500);
  smooth();
  b = new Blackhole();
}

void draw() {
  background(#202020);
  b.display();
}

class Blackhole {
  float speed = 0;

  int [] eSize = {0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175};
  float radius = 100;
  int numPoints = 16;
  float angle = TWO_PI/(float)numPoints;

  Blackhole() {

  }

  void display() {

    speed = speed + 0.05;
    float pulse = noise(speed);
    pulse = map(pulse, 0, 1, 150, 175);

    noFill();
    stroke(255, 100);
     for ( int j = 0; j < eSize.length; j++) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {

        float pulseRadius = radius + pulse + eSize[j];
        float x = pulseRadius * sin(angle*i)+width/2;
        float y = pulseRadius * cos(angle*i)+height/2;
        ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Just as an exploration, [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/CirclesOfCircles/) is a javascript demo of the code using a function and sine calls to vary the number of points in the large circle and the two radii.

```java
int numPoints = 16;


void setup(){
  size(750,500);
  smooth();
  noFill();
}
void draw(){
  background(#202020);
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numPoints; i++){
    stroke(255, (i+1) * 10);
    circleOfCircles((int)map(sin(frameCount * .001 + i),-1.0,1.0,12 , 64),//number of sides
                         map(sin(frameCount * .010 + i),-1.0,1.0,100,225),//large radius
                         map(sin(frameCount * .100 + i),-1.0,1.0,  1, 30));//small radius
  }
}
/*
    draws a large circle with each vertex drawn as a smaller circle
    sides = circle detail, the more sides, the more detaild the circle will be
    largeRadius = large circle radius
    smallRadius = radius of each small circle
*/
void circleOfCircles(int sides,float largeRadius, float smallRadius){
  float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < sides; i++){
    pushMatrix();
      rotate(angleIncrement * i);
      translate(largeRadius,0);
      ellipse(0,0,smallRadius,smallRadius);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

[image: circles animation preview]

Have fun!

Comment: Wow thank you for breaking everything down, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helps and thank you for the accept. Feel free to vote up as well ;) It was fun exploring. Check out [this coloured version](http://lifesine.eu/so/CirclesOfCirclesFilled/) I ended up with (drag mouseX and mouseY to change parameters). I'd love to see what crazy patterns you will come up with :)